# Windchill - Create tab

Tags: ptc-windchill

i created *custom-actionmodels.xml*

```
<model name="partInfoPageTabSet" resource="com.ptc.core.ui.navigationRB">
     <submodel name="windimTabModel" />
   </model>

<model name="windimTabModel" resourceBundle="com.windim.windimRB">
   <action name="windimTabAction" type="windim"/>
</model>
```

*custom-actions.xml* also

```
   <objecttype name="windim" resourceBundle="com.windim.windimRB">
      <action name="windimTabAction" resourceBundle="com.windim.windimRB">
        <command windowType="page" url="netmarkets/jsp/part/info.jsp"/>
      </action>
   </objecttype>
```

and compiled *windimRB.java* in */codebase/com/windim*

```
package com.windim;

import wt.util.resource.*;

@RBUUID("com.windim.windimRB")
public final class windimRB extends WTListResourceBundle {
   @RBEntry("WindIM")
   // @RBComment("Resolving issues")
   // @RBArgComment0("Any string...")
   public static final String WINDIM_TABMODEL = "object_windimTabModel";
}
```

and tab does not work.

Comment: Where you have created the custom tab??

Comment: It shows when you are in part info page, drawing info page...

Answer (score 1):

```
object_windimTabModel
```

turned intoto

```
object.windimTabModel
```